# how to obtain logical/mathematical maturity for studying mathematical logic at the graduate level?

Tags: logic

I want to study logic/mathematical logic at the graduate level, and the master's is in Pure and Applied Logic, and the master's guide says the following :

"the formal and mathematical level of our master is
very high. Even though the main problems that are studied in the master are
mostly rooted in deep philosophical questions, the methods employed to address
these questions are mostly of formal or mathematical nature" and they go on to emphasize " Students who do not have
a proper background in formal/mathematical reasoning can be required to do
preparatory courses before they are accepted to enrol "

I would really like to prepare for this master's and have the required mathematical skill to be able to do mathematical and formal reasoning as desired.

My background:

I am a computer systems engineering graduate and have taken some maths courses of course, but they don't really count because I hardly passed them and the quality of education in my country is not very good.
In high school though I studied solid geometry (enjoyed it very much), probability(didn't enjoy it), calculus(didn't enjoy it), statics and dynamics (enjoyed both although they might be related to physics more) and I think that maybe these studies could count, but I am a little rusty since this has been more than 7 years ago.

So I would really appreciate it if someone could suggest to me some books I could follow to gain or assure myself that I have this mathematical or formal reasoning maturity that the master's might require. it would be great if they are related to the field of study of the master's somehow or at least be related to the things that I enjoyed studying in high school although it's not necessary, the most important thing is that I can follow/understand them with my background.
Thank you all for your help!

**Edit:**

The courses in the master's :

Computability
Basic Set Theory
Introduction to Mathematical Logic
Non-Classical Logics
Orders, Lattices and Boolean Algebras
Universal Algebra
Algebraic Logic
Basic Model Theory
Combinatorial Set Theory
Mathematical Logic
Modal Logic
The Development of Formal Logic
Complexity
Abstract Algebraic Logic
Advanced Model Theory
Many-Valued Logics
Models of Set Theory
Proof Theory and Automated Theorem Proving

Comment: Are you applying to a philosophy department or a mathematics department?

Comment: @ShyPerson the master's itself is made by a collaboration of departments but I apply to the department of philosophy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an unbelievably action-packed programme for a Master's level degree!!

In response to your query, two different angles of approach:

1. My freely downloadable [*Beginning Mathematical Logic*](https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl) is a Study Guide, suggesting introductory readings beginning at sub-Masters level. Take a look at the main introductory suggestions on First-Order Logic, Computability, Set Theory as useful preparation. Tackling mid-level books will help develop your appreciation of mathematical approaches to logic.
2. That Study Guide is focussed (surprise, surprise) on math logic topics. What other neighbouring areas of mathematics might it be worth looking at? It will depend on what you find interesting! But I'd suggest some elementary analysis (because you want to know e.g. a bit about how set theoretic ideas feature) and some algebra (because it is approachable and quite fun). There is large number of suitable books. I'll mention, not quite at random, three books I like, which are interesting in their own right but will also help develop "mathematical maturity" and an appreciation of rigorous proofs. The most elementary is Alan Beardon's *Algebra and Geometry* (CUP) -- a first year Cambridge Tripos book, very nicely done. Then try Stephen Abbott, *Understanding Analysis* (Springer), written with zest and nicely structured, and Paulo Aluffi, *Algebra: Notes from the Underground* (CUP).

Comment: For what it's worth, I've found Peter Smith's "Beginning Mathematical Logic" to be a gem of a find on SE.  The writing style is enjoyable, it gives a good overview of necessary concepts & notation, and it gives incredibly helpful guidance on contextualizing the various angles & levels of difficulty that different books/disciplines have with respect to the topics covered.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have very specific advice, but I can offer a general strategy.  (It's compatible with Peter Smith's more specific advice, which sounds excellent to me.)  I am sympathetic to your situation, and excited for you because philosophy of logic is a great subject.  (I don't work on it but have studied some basics and have great respect for the field.)  One of the challenges in choosing math books is that they range over several orders of magnitude of difficulty, and the titles don't always tell you what level a book is at.

Of course it would be good to study logic in preparation, but the most important thing, I suspect is the "mathematical maturity" part.  For this purpose, I would suggest the following related strategies.  It might be that you don't need this advice, or that some other kind of advice would be more valuable to you, but this is what would (what did) work for me.

1. Look at math books in any area that interests you (including logic).  Go to libraries and bookstores, if you can, so that you can look at the actual books.  (Don't restrict yourself to freely available PDFs, unless you have no choice.) Buy books if you want, but try reading them first.  Then, choose books that are just a little bit too hard.  I mean that some parts of the book will not be understandable at first, but if you spend a lot of time on a page, you can understand it.  I think that this process leads to deeper intuitions about mathematical reasoning more quickly.  If you don't find logic textbooks that fit this requirement for you, that's OK; you can study other sorts of math books for the same general purpose.
2. You definitely want books with proofs, and you want to study the proofs (or at least some of them) until you understand them.  If you study proofs in different books by different authors, you'll start to get a feel for different common ways of structuring proofs and their surrounding remarks.  You'll also get a feel for what sorts of things are being taken for granted.
3. I personally also find it helpful to use two or three books on the same topic at the same time.  Sometimes one book has a part that is completely opaque to me, even after I try for a long time.  But another book might be the one that makes those ideas clear, even though it's not ideal for me in other respects.

Maybe all of that is obvious, but if not, I thought it was worth saying.

And of course you have to decide what works for you.  For example, maybe for you it would be better to find a series of books that start at a level that is comfortable, but then gradually get harder, rather than following my strategy of choosing books that are a bit too difficult.